# Add days to a date php object and then verify if it is between 2 date objects

Tags: php, mysql, web

In my fitness system, i have to show some general status on the index page.
I have the date when the user was added to the database, the actual date, and the actual date plus 15 days.
So i have to verify if the added user date is between the actual date and the actual date plus 15 days.
This verify must be inside the query, like.. SELECT * FROM users WHERE date (is between today and today+15 date)...

What is the best way to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: _Scratch that, you're looking for a MySQL function_ (Was asking about PHP version for date/time function capabilities)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT   *
FROM     users
WHERE    date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)
```

See the other [Date Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) available in MySQL.